# Firebase-CLI | Skip 'yes/no' confirmation when deleting from database | batch

Tags: batch-file, firebase, command-line, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

The title pretty much says it all. For one of my websites, I have a server computer running a batch file that updates the database after performing an action for a user. After it finishes this action, it deletes the user's request on the database. How can I automate the process of deleting something on the database? How can I skip the y/n confirmation (I know that with some commands you can use /q or /s, but I can't seem to find the version of /q for Firebase commands)? Answers should be in batch, please.

Answer (score 5):

Use `-f` or `--force`. From the CLI helptext:

```
Usage: firebase database:remove [options] <path>

remove data from your Firebase at the specified path

Options:
  -f, --force            pass this option to bypass confirmation prompt
  --instance <instance>  use the database <instance>.firebaseio.com (if omitted, use default database instance)
  -h, --help             output usage information
```

Comment: --y or --confirm are not valid options any more in the latest version of firebase cli. Hence, the answer from @Ronan Ca with -f is the only way to go.

Comment: Edited to reflect the newer syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

If someone need to do the same for **firebase functions:delete**, just use `--force` option as described here :

```
firebase functions:delete --help
Usage: firebase functions:delete [options] [filters...]

delete one or more Cloud Functions by name or group name.

Options:
  --region <region>  Specify region of the function to be deleted. If omitted, functions from all regions whose names match the filters will be deleted.
  -f, --force        No confirmation. Otherwise, a confirmation prompt will appear.
  -h, --help         output usage information
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I ended up just going into the firebase-update.js script on my PC, and commenting out the prompt.